# UWP - programmatically trigger a Windows PC Lock

Tags: uwp, screen-lock

I have been searching for a while for how to trigger a screen lock on windows programmatically from a UWP app, but the only thing found from MSDN is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.lockscreen?view=winrt-19041) and it doesn't even trigger a lock screen event. It creates a new lock screen.
My use case is this: I verify users via a UWP i have developed. If for one user the verification fails, i want to trigger the PC lock for this user.

Is this even possible through a UWP?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no such api that could take over lock screen within uwp platform. For [`Windows.ApplicationModel.LockScreen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.lockscreen?view=winrt-19041) api that is use to let your app show an indicator on the lock screen, not for taking over the lock screen. For more info please refer link [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/issues/726).

Comment: Thank you for the information! The other option i can think of is programmatically create an event that would simulate pressing Windows button + L button in keyboard in UWP. Is this possible in UWP? I know it can be done in wpf

Comment: Sure, you could injecting input in uwp, for more please research Martin's blog **Injecting input in UWP apps**

Comment: I used win + l with injecting before, unfortunately, it will not lock the system.